# SetUserAlarm Okuma THINC API C#

Tags: c#, okuma

I am working on an app for an Okuma lathe.

I would like to be able to put the lathe into an alarm state from the app. I am not getting any errors and the app runs on the machine, but it doesn't go into an NC alarm state.

The line before it does change the text of alarmLabel.
I am using alarmLabel for troubleshooting.
Can anyone provide an example of SetUserAlarm in C#?
Does anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```c#
alarmLabel.Text = "Alarm ON";
objCMDMachine.SetUserAlarm(  
    Okuma.CLCMDAPI.Enumerations.UserAlarmEnum.C,  
    "Test Alarm",  
    Okuma.CLCMDAPI.Enumerations.UserAlarmSubSystemEnum.All
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code there looks okay to me.

To successfully generate a machine alarm, the API must have the licensed feature `UserAlarm`.
(**Okuma.Lathe.UserAlarm** in the okuma.api.lic license file).

You can confirm that a machine has this option by using the [SCOUT library](https://github.com/OkumaAmerica/Open-API-SDK/tree/master/Scout):

> ```
>       UserAlarmLathe = Okuma.Scout.LicenseChecker.License_UserAlarm_L;
>         if (UserAlarmLathe.Status == Enums.LicenseStatus.Valid)
>         {
>             // ...
>         }
> ```

Additionally, the machine on which the API resides must also have the `THiNC ALARM` option.

If your machine does not have the option, it can be ordered by contacting your Okuma Distributor and asking for option code **" :911-0010 - THiNC ALARM "**

The presence of this option can be confirmed by checking the Lathe Spec Code `NC-B No. 4, Bit 3`. You can check this spec code in your application using either THINC API or SCOUT.

## Using THINC API:

> ```
>    Okuma.CLDATAPI.DataAPI.CSpec SpecCodeClass = new Okuma.CLDATAPI.DataAPI.CSpec();  
>     bool THiNK_ALARM = SpecCodeClass.GetBSpecCode(4, 3);  
>     if (THiNK_ALARM)  
>     {  
>         // ...  
>     }
> ```

## Using SCOUT:

> ```
>     if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.MachineSpecCodeFileExists)
>     {
>         if (Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.SpecFileIsValid)
>         {
>             bool THiNK_ALARM = Okuma.Scout.SpecCode.NCB.Bit(  
>                                    Okuma.Scout.Enums.NCBSpecGroup.NCB1MG, 4, 3);
>             if (THiNK_ALARM)
>             {
>                 // ...
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thank you Okuma.Scott. The lathe does not have Thinc Alarm option. I found out the option would need to be purchased.